# Error 'Expected % arguments but found %" al lanzar excepción

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de herencias y de trhow extends exception y me encuentro con una serie de problemas.

De primeras, por una parte tengo el siguiente archivo:

```
public class Product {
    private int referenceId = 0;
    private String reference;
    private String name;
    private int publicationYear;
    private String description;
    private double price;
    private ProductException productexception;

    public Product() throws ProductException{
        setName("Lorem Ipsum");
        setPublicationYear(2011);
        setDescription("lorem ipsum description");
        setPrice(7.50);
        createReference();
    }

    public Product(String name, int publicationYear,String description, double price) throws ProductException{
        setName(name);
        setPublicationYear(publicationYear);
        setDescription(description);
        setPrice(price);
        createReference();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) throws ProductException{
        if (name.length() > 50) {
            throw new ProductException(productexception.MSG_ERR_NAME);
        } else {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

El otro archivo, donde tengo las exepciones es el siguiente:

```
public class ProductException extends Exception {
    public static String MSG_ERR_NAME = "[ERROR] Team's name cannot be longer than 50 characters";
    public static String MSG_ERR_PUBLICATION_YEAR = "[ERROR] Product's publicationYear cannot be later than current year";
    public static String MSG_ERR_DESCRIPTION = "[ERROR] Product's description cannot be longer than 250 characters";
    public static String MSG_ERR_NEGATIVE = "[ERROR] Product's price cannot be negative";
```

El problema es que no acabo de llamar bien el archivo de las expeciones en el constructor y no entiendo el porque.

En el primer throw new, me salta el error de "Expected 0 arguments but found 1".

Alguna ayuda?

Gracias

Comment: Puede ser que no haya definido un constructor con parametros para su clase ProductException

Comment: si? como quedaria eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error

> 'Expected % arguments but found %'

se da, en general, cuando el compilador encuentra un método que coincide en nombre con el que se intenta invocar, pero no encuentra una versión del mismo que coincida con el numero de argumentos con que se invoca.

En este caso intenta invocar un constructor de la clase ProductException con un parámetro, pero solo existe el constructor por defecto (sin parametros).

Debe definir un un constructor con parametros para la clase ProductException que reciba parametros, y en el invocar el constructor con parametros de la superclase

A continuación el código para definirle el constructor con parámetros

```
public class ProductException extends Exception 
{
  /*Bloque de constantes*/
  public ProductException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: funciono! muchas gracias!